# If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty u_n$ , $\sum_{n=0}^\infty v_n$ both converge, then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty u_n v_n / (u_n + v_n)$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I have to prove if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty u_n$ , $\sum_{n=0}^\infty v_n$ are convergent series of positive terms, then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty u_n v_n / (u_n + v_n)$ converges.

I'm not sure if my proof is correct because it is pretty straight forward. We have that

$$u_n v_n / (u_n + v_n)\leq u_n v_n/u_n = v_n$$

Hence the convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty v_n$ implies the convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty u_n v_n / (u_n + v_n)$. Is this correct?

My "arachnid sense" tells me to use the Cauchy Product because there is no information given of the absolute convergence of the initial series but I don't know how to use it in this case. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks fine to me...and the new series definitely is an elementwise product one, not Cauchy's.

Comment: @anderstood See the first line of the question :).

Comment: @ErickWong OK, I was looking for the sign $>0$. Previous comment deleted.

Comment: Absolute versus conditional convergence is not an issue, everything is positive.

Comment: @AndréNicolas of course, I overlooked that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\dfrac{u_nv_n}{u_n+v_n} \leq \dfrac{u_n+v_n}{4}$

Comment: Sure, but what's wrong with the OP's solution?  It proves the stronger result that only one of the series needs to converge.

Comment: Very nice inequality, thank you! Is my approach also correct?

Comment: It is ....fine.